# React - async used with componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs

Im working through [this](https://auth0.com/blog/react-tutorial-building-and-securing-your-first-app/?_ga=2.228145178.663623128.1587895169-1598383978.1587895169) example and would appreciate some help understanding the following section of code.

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;
    const question = (await axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/${params.questionId}`)).data;
    this.setState({
      question,
    });
  }
```

1. I haven't seen the string `async` before `componentDidMount()` up until now.  What does this achieve?  I know that after all the elements of the page are rendered correctly this method is called but what is async doing here?
2. Please help me understand what `const { match: { params } } = this.props;` is doing here?

Comment: I feel like this is a general poor react coding style because componentDidMount belongs to reacts lifecyle. I'd call a seperate method inside component did mount which can of course be asnychronous. But I'd personally stay away from your sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**
You declare a function `async` when you want to use `await` inside that function to wait for an asynchronous call to return. I don't think you can use `async` on `componentDidMount` but you can use a promise instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/${params.questionId}`)
         .then(res => {
             const question = res.data;
             this.setState({ question });
         });
}
```

**2.**
This is called destructuring, it means that you want to extract `params` from `this.props`

```
const { match: { params } } = this.props;
```

It is equivalent to:

```
const params = this.props.match.params
```